# What does this js syntax mean?

Tags: javascript

I came across something like this while I was looking at preexisting `JavaScript` code. So I tried to write similar code and it worked correctly (or rather I don't know if its working correctly or not)

The code is like this

```
//main.js
(function() {
    alert("am I being called?");
})();
```

I included this main.js in my index.html and as soon as I refreshed the page, the alert popped up.

What is this?

and what JavaScript concepts/features do I need to study to correctly understand this?

Comment: This must be the second most popular question after "my AJAX is undefined!"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
(function () {
    ...
})();
```

is known as an [Immediately-Invoked Function Expression](http://benalman.com/news/2010/11/immediately-invoked-function-expression/). IIFEs are often used to provide a scope for variables and functions to reduce global namespace pollution.